# Defining user roles "restfully" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a `user` resource which has many `roles`.

Users should be able to assign roles to other users, for example admins should be able to sire other admins.

**Is the following a good restful definition of the resource?**

```
POST    /roles/                        | create a new role definition
to: roles#create                       |
DELETE  /roles/:role_id                | remove a role  
to: roles#destroy                      |
GET     /roles/                        | list roles   
to: roles#index

POST    /users/:user_id/roles/         | add a new role to user
to: user_roles#create                  |
DELETE  /users/:user_id/roles/:role_id | remove role from user
to: user_roles#create                  |
GET     /users/:user_id/roles/         | list roles assigned to user
```

I´m using Rails 4, Devise, CanCan and Rolify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would keep it simpler than that. I would have it all be under a `users` resource (so you always have access to the user.

```
POST    /users/:user_id/roles/         | add a new role to user
to: user_roles#create                  |
DELETE  /users/:user_id/roles/:role_id | remove role from user
to: user_roles#delete                  |
GET     /users/:user_id/roles/         | list roles assigned to user
```

Your `/users` route could list roles for all users as well, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I would make removing or adding a role to a developer level for safety reasons, thus why I wouldn't even have routes for that.  But that's just my $0.02™.